# Webpack renames functions

Tags: javascript, webpack

Hello i have some problems with webpack. I have this config for webpack

```
module.exports = {
    name: "front",
    mode: "production",
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: [
        './jquery/photoswipe.addon_offer_and_order.min.js',
        './jquery/photoswipe.min.js',
        './jquery/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js',
        './deprecated.js',
        './index.js',
    ],
    output: {
        filename: "index.min.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    optimization: {
        moduleIds: 'named'
    }
}
```

All good but i have a deprecated.js and have all deprecated functions in it...

Example:

```
function updateSearchCharacteristic(url, category_id) {
    console.warn("This method is deprecated please use shopSearch.updateCharacteristic()");
    return shopSearch.updateCharacteristic(url, category_id);
}

function moveBlockAnfrageGuest() {
    console.warn("This method is deprecated please use shopUser.moveOrderAndOfferLinkForGuest()");
    return shopUser.moveOrderAndOfferLinkForGuest();
}
```

Webpack rename all these functions, if someone used the old functions, he does not see errors and the return does not work ..
How not to rename functions in this file, but compress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem :

```
npm install -D script-loader terser-webpack-plugin
```

Added a module  into config and 'require' a plugin

```
const TerserPlugin  = require('terser-webpack-plugin')

 module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /deprecated.js/,
                use : [
                    {
                        loader: 'script-loader',
                        options:{
                            plugins: [
                                new TerserPlugin({
                                    terserOptions: {
                                        keep_fnames: true,
                                    }
                                })
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```